# Subtracting two multi-indexed data frames based on both indices

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have two dataframes that look something like below:

```
df1 = 
          val
id1 id2
foo  1     50
     2    100
     4    200
bar  1     25
     4    100
     8    200
baz  2     75
     4    150


df2 = 
          val
id1 id2
foo  1     60
     2    200
     3    100
bar  1     50
     4    101
     8    202
baz  2     70
     5    155
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe, that compares both indices and subtracts the `val` column only if **both** indices match.

How to generate the data:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'id1':['foo','foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','baz', 'baz'],
   'id2':[1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 8, 2, 4], 
   'val':[50, 100, 200, 25, 100, 200, 75, 150]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1.set_index(['id1', 'id2'], inplace=True)
```

```
import pandas as pd
d2 = {'id1':['foo','foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar','baz', 'baz'],
   'id2':[1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 5], 
   'val':[60, 200, 100, 50, 101, 202, 70, 155]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2.set_index(['id1', 'id2'], inplace=True)
```

I'm quite new to python and multi-indexes are the bane of my life right now.

Comment: you can simply subtract like this, `print df1-df2`. Note df2 assigns df1's data

Comment: I recommend you make: df = df.reset_index() until you have a little more experience with multindex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly subtract two data frames. It will subtract the value where indices matched.

like below,

```
res=df1-df2
```

Output:

```
           val
id1 id2       
bar 1    -25.0
    4     -1.0
    8     -2.0
baz 2      5.0
    4      NaN
    5      NaN
foo 1    -10.0
    2   -100.0
    3      NaN
    4      NaN
           val
```

If you wan to see only matched records try like below,

```
res[res['val'].notnull()]
```

Output:

```
id1 id2       
bar 1    -25.0
    4     -1.0
    8     -2.0
baz 2      5.0
foo 1    -10.0
    2   -100.0
```

for more details follow this link  [multi-indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

If you have multiple columns and want to perform subtraction for single column use below

```
df1['res']=df1['val']-df2['val']
```

Output:

```
         val    res
id1 id2            
foo 1     50  -10.0
    2    100 -100.0
    4    200    NaN
bar 1     25  -25.0
    4    100   -1.0
    8    200   -2.0
baz 2     75    5.0
    4    150    NaN
```

This above snippet perform subtraction for `val` column and store this into new column called `res`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works in the case above but not in cases where multiple columns exist (containing strings). Is there any way to do this without dropping unwanted columns?